# Sound icon missing from top menu

Tags: unity, sound, menu

The sound icon from the top menu bar is missing. It does however appear on the login screen and the guest account. I can still adjust my volume using keyboard keys but I liked the sound icon because it let me control Rhythmbox.

I noticed there are a lot of questions about this issue but all of the answers say to run $gnome-sound-applet & which does not seem to work. Does anybody know how I can fix this?

Edit: running "gsettings reset com.canonical.indicator.sound visible" fixed the problem

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Run in a terminal:

```
gsettings get com.canonical.indicator.sound visible
```

If the outcome is is "false", change it with the command:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.sound visible true
```

Comment: Bizarrely, running the first command returned "true" on my system, even though the indicator was missing. Running the second command fixed it anyways.

Comment: It happens to me every time the system boots where the previous session was shut down having the sound muted.

Going to System Settings / Sound, I found the Mute option was checked.
Unchecking it, or changing the volume form the Sound settings, caused the icon to show up on the Panel immediately.

I was looking for a way to automatically unmute the sound at startup, in order to force the icon showing up, but found the gsettings command mentioned by Jacob useful (even though the get command returns true, setting it again had the expected effect), and it retains the muted state.