# com.canonical.indicator.sound visible key is gone

Tags: xubuntu, indicator, xfce, indicator-sound, xfce-panel

I was missing the sound indicator from the xfce4 unity notification indicator panel, so I tried the steps in [Sound icon missing from top menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471675/sound-icon-missing-from-top-menu/471678) to fix it.

I discovered that `com.canonical.indicator.sound visible` is literally gone. How do I add it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the `indicator-sound` package was missing. This probably occurred as a result of purging `pulseaudio` to fix its issues. Reinstalling it immediately made it available.